# missing implementation error when creating eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, liquibase

I am trying to use liquibase to build a new plugin,
when trying to test the plugin I keep getting the following error:
 liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of 
liquibase.logging.Logger

anyone have any idea why eclipse refuse to load this part?